80's - 90's Sci-fi movie or mini tv movie 2 friends are in computer adventure game racing
I've tried to figure out this movie for 30 years or more. Somewhere in the early 90s all I can remember is an english sci-fi movie on local TV and there 2 boys (I think) inside a computer simulation/game (not Tron) and I'm assuming their friends on the outside PC console. The only scene I remember is a race between the protagonists and the bad guys. The protagonist has a regular car like a beetle or something and the other guys have a muscle car. the race begins and it is not going too well.. then the scene cuts to the friends in the real world on the console and they do some hack coding stuff and change the beater car to Lamborghini or some Euro sports car (white-grey I think). and the other guys are in shock as they have a different car and they cross the finish line.
I hope there's some legend out there who can help me. Thankyou in advance.

Herbie Goes Virtual! :D

hahaha... i wish
